# Which word(s) need (or need not) to be changed to make this answer proper?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30352950/2173917), I received a comment (*and probably a downvote, not the point of discussion here, though*) from the OP saying

> ....Thank you for the answer, but your first and last comments are condescending and unhelpful.

I already linked to the answer. Can I request for a review of the language used in my answer and *possible* suggestions for the improvement please?

Comment: @Servy it is there still. However, my point is not about the _comment_, about my _language_. I'm not a native english speaker ani I maybe say something very wrong which I did not mean. So, asking. :-)

Comment: OP needs to grow some internet callouses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I don't see anything wrong with the last sentence in your answer, but

> There goes another improper usage of sizeof().

does seem condescending. It sounds like "Here we go again... why do I have to keep repeating this?" So, why not just get rid of it and get to the part where you answer the question?

Comment: Thanks, updated. Can you please review? and what about the _last line_ OP referred to?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't see anything wrong with it now. The OP might have just been biased by the first sentence, so was a little bit sensitive. I'd flag the comments as obsolete/not constructive now.

Comment: Thank you. Good night (in Indian Standard Time) :-)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose somebody could read

> There goes another improper usage of sizeof().

as you meaning something along the lines of:

> Ugh, this again? Yet another idiot making the same simple/common mistake.

(I'm not a C person, I don't know if this is a common mistake)

It doesn't seem to add anything to the answer so I'd probably just remove that sentence entirely. The rest - including the last line that they referred to - seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Thanks, updated. Review please. and what about the _last line_ OP referred to?

Comment: @SouravGhosh The language looks fine to me. The last sentence seems like a perfectly valid, and definitely not condescending, comment to make based on my (very minimal) understanding of the subject matter.

Comment: Thank you. Good night (in Indian Standard Time) :-)